# Needed to add a logo to an image banner section of Dawn theme on Shopify

Tags: html, css, json, shopify, liquid

While I am very familiar with HTML & CSS but Liquid is a whole new frontier to me. I'm working on a website using Shopify and I would love add an image block into the default Image Banner section of Dawn theme. I know there's a bit a coding involve but I don't know how to, would anyone be of assistance? Thanks in advance!

I dug around the *image-banner.liquid* file but if I were to add a div, it would prompt something along the line of modifying the .json file and wouldn't be able to use the logo file that was linked within Shopify.

Comment: Hi! do you want full section code or just Schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**full section code with logo section schema.  *image-banner.liquid***

```
{{ 'section-image-banner.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{%- if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank -%}
  {%- style -%}
  @media screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}:not(.banner--mobile-bottom) .banner__content::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }
  {%- endstyle -%}
{%- endif -%}

{%- style -%}
  #Banner-{{ section.id }}::after {
    opacity: {{ section.settings.image_overlay_opacity | divided_by: 100.0 }};
  }
{%- endstyle -%}

<div id="Banner-{{ section.id }}" class="banner banner--content-align-{{ section.settings.desktop_content_alignment }} banner--content-align-mobile-{{ section.settings.mobile_content_alignment }} banner--{{ section.settings.image_height }}{% if section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile and section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner--stacked{% endif %}{% if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank %} banner--adapt{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} banner--mobile-bottom{%- endif -%}{% if section.settings.show_text_box == false %} banner--desktop-transparent{% endif %}">
  {%- if section.settings.image != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      <img
        srcset="{%- if section.settings.image.width >= 375 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 375 }} 375w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 550 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 550 }} 550w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 750 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 750 }} 750w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1100 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1100 }} 1100w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1500 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1500 }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 1780 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1780 }} 1780w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 2000 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 2000 }} 2000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 3000 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 3000 }} 3000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image.width >= 3840 -%}{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 3840 }} 3840w,{%- endif -%}
          {{ section.settings.image | image_url }} {{ section.settings.image.width }}w"
        sizes="{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile %}(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw{% elsif section.settings.image_2 != blank %}50vw{% else %}100vw{% endif %}"
        src="{{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1500 }}"
        loading="lazy"
        alt="{{ section.settings.image.alt | escape }}"
        width="{{ section.settings.image.width }}"
        height="{{ section.settings.image.width | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio }}"
        {% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %}class="banner__media-image-half"{% endif %}
      >
    </div>
  {%- elsif section.settings.image_2 == blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {{ 'lifestyle-2' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if section.settings.image_2 != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      <img
        srcset="{%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 375 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 375 }} 375w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 750 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 750 }} 750w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 1100 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1100 }} 1100w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 1500 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1500 }} 1500w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 1780 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1780 }} 1780w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 2000 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 2000 }} 2000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 3000 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 3000 }} 3000w,{%- endif -%}
          {%- if section.settings.image_2.width >= 3840 -%}{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 3840 }} 3840w,{%- endif -%}
          {{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url }} {{ section.settings.image_2.width }}w"
        sizes="{% if section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile %}(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw{% elsif section.settings.image != blank %}50vw{% else %}100vw{% endif %}"
        src="{{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1500 }}"
        loading="lazy"
        alt="{{ section.settings.image_2.alt | escape }}"
        width="{{ section.settings.image_2.width }}"
        height="{{ section.settings.image_2.width | divided_by: section.settings.image_2.aspect_ratio }}"
        {% if section.settings.image != blank %}class="banner__media-image-half"{% endif %}
      >
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  <div class="banner__content banner__content--{{ section.settings.desktop_content_position }} page-width">
    <div class="banner__box content-container content-container--full-width-mobile color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }}">
      {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        {%- case block.type -%}
          {%- when 'image' -%}
          <img src="{{ block.settings.img | img_url: 'master' }}">  
          {%- when 'heading' -%}
            <h2 class="banner__heading {{ block.settings.heading_size }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.heading | escape }}</span>
            </h2>
          {%- when 'text' -%}
            <div class="banner__text {{ block.settings.text_style }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.text | escape }}</span>
            </div>
          {%- when 'buttons' -%}
            <div class="banner__buttons{% if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank and block.settings.button_label_2 != blank %} banner__buttons--multiple{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_1 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_1 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_1 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_1 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_2 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_2 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_2 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_2 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_2 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}

            </div>
        {%- endcase -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.image-banner.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image_2",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_2.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "image_overlay_opacity",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 10,
      "unit": "%",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_overlay_opacity.label",
      "default": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_height",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "small",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "medium",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "large",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "medium",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "adapt_height_first_image",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.adapt_height_first_image.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.adapt_height_first_image.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "desktop_content_position",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "top-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "top-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "top-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__4.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__5.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__6.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__7.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__8.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__9.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "middle-center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_text_box",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.show_text_box.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "desktop_content_alignment",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "color_scheme",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "accent-1",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "accent-2",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "background-1",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "background-2",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.options__4.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "inverse",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.options__5.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "background-1",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.header.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "mobile_content_alignment",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "stack_images_on_mobile",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.stack_images_on_mobile.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_text_below",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.show_text_below.label"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "heading",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.heading.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "heading",
          "default": "Image banner",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.heading.settings.heading.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "heading_size",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "h2",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h1",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h0",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "h1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "text",
          "default": "Give customers details about the banner image(s) or content on the template.",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_style",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "body",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "subtitle",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "caption-with-letter-spacing",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "body",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "name": "logo",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "img",
          "label": "logo Image"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "buttons",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label_1",
          "default": "Button label",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_1.label",
          "info": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_1.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "button_link_1",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_link_1.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "button_style_secondary_1",
          "default": false,
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_style_secondary_1.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label_2",
          "default": "Button label",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_2.label",
          "info": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_2.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "button_link_2",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_link_2.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "button_style_secondary_2",
          "default": false,
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_style_secondary_2.label"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.presets.name",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "heading"
        },
        {
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "type": "buttons"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```